# Kafka Magic Tool configuration with SSL

Tags: apache-kafka

Trying to register a kafka cluster in my local with ssl but i am not able connect though i am providing all details.

[image]

I trying to register kafka cluster in kafka magic tool .
I have provided all info with all ssl details.
CA location i am giving truststore path from my local.
getting error in connection .
am i missing any format?

Comment: You seem to be missing settings for the public and private key paths and I don't think the truststore is a CA file

Comment: @Onecricketeer
can u elaborate little more ? like public and private key paths . do you mean I need to decompile the jks file and place the generated file in that field ?

Comment: The description shown in the UI says it wants PEM files, not JKS (because I assume the tool is written using NodeJS, not Java), but yes. I'm just guessing; I've never used this tool. If you want a more specific answer, perhaps the "Feedback" link in the upper right would help you more